# ArCore ArFrame Hide Camera Image but preserve HandMotion Animation

Tags: android, fragment, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Is there any way to preserve the hand motion animation when initializing ArCore but simultaneously getting rid of the camera picture - which is displayed behind the hand motion animation.

I am using

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/Ar"
    android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
```

and currently I am hiding the whole Fragment with:

```
fragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Ar);

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    fm.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
            .hide(fragment)
            .commit();
```

Any help is appreciated.